# Error CSP does not support DSA algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, signature, dsa, hsm

I get this error while trying to set up a DSACryptoServiceProvider to be used for a DSA Signature on a HSM that accepts DSA Signature :

> "The specified cryptographic service provider (CSP) does not support this key algorithm."

**Call stack :**

> at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
>          at System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
>          at ProjektDemoHSM.Controller.setDSAAlgo(Dictionary`2 listProp) in Controller.cs:line 788

**Code  :**

```
CSP = new CspParameters(1, "Luna Cryptographic Services for Microsoft Windows");
l.788 : DSAcsp = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(CSP);
```

And I am sure the `CSP` accepts `DSA` as : (I spared you the whole list of supported algorithms)

```
c:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\KSP>certutil -csp "Luna Cryptographic Services for Microsoft Windows" -csptest   
  Signature Algorithms:
    DSA

  Asymmetric Algorithms:
    DSA

CertUtil: -csptest command completed successfully.
```

If anyone had any idea what could cause such an error, I am interessed. FYI, I am running on `.NET 3.5`, and trying to use an HSM Luna SA. I have no problem using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` or `ECDsaCng`, but ``DSA just won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're passing in `1` for the CSP Provider type (the first parameter to `CspParameters`), which is `PROV_RSA_FULL`. Try `13` or `3` instead of 1.